# Using $http in a controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.2 app. My app has a controller that looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 
  function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {    
    $scope.newItem_Click = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'item-dialog.html',
            size: 'md',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.item = { typeId: 7, id: '-1' };
                $scope.saveItem = function (did) {                    
                    if ($scope.item.description) {
                        if ($scope.item.description.trim().length > 0) {
                            $scope.item.departmentId = did;
                            $modalInstance.close($scope.item);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Please enter your description.');
                    }
                };

                $scope.cancelItem = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };

                $scope.getItems = function (departmentId) {
                    var url = '/api/items?departmentId=' + departmentId;
                    return $http.get(url).then(
                        function (response) {
                            var results = response.data;
                            results.reverse();

                            var items = [];
                            var i = 0;

                            angular.forEach(results, function (item, key) {
                                var local = results[i].CreatedUTC;
                                results[i].CreatedOn = new Date(local);
                                items.push(item);
                                i = i + 1;
                            });
                            console.log(items);
                            $scope.items = items;
                        }
                    );
                };

                $scope.$on('list-updated', function () {
                    $scope.getItems($scope.item.id);
                });
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(
            function (item) {
                var apiUrl = '/api/items';
                apiUrl = apiUrl + '?typeId=' + item.typeId;
                if (item.departmentId!== '-1') {
                    apiUrl = apiUrl + '&departmentId=' + item.departmentId;
                }
                apiUrl = apiUrl + '&content=' + item.description;
                apiUrl = encodeURI(apiUrl);

                $http.post(apiUrl).then(
                    function () {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('list-updated');
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

For some reason, I can successfully save an item. The `console.log(items)` statement displays all of the items as I would expect. However, my view is not being updated. What am I doing wrong? I suspect its because I'm assigning $scope.items inside of the HTTP response. Yet, I'm not sure how to get around it.

I know this is not recommended. However, I am in crunch mode.

Comment: Your inner `$scope` in your modal is hiding your outer `$scope`. Which `$scope` should `items` lie within?

Comment: If you're looking for a quick fix, try either adding $scope.$apply() after assigning the items to $scope.items or...wrap the assignment inside of an angular $timeout.